# Eliminating the border for the cover block in YITH Wonder theme

Tags: css

On the front (home) page of my website, which uses a child theme of YITH Wonder, the cover block has a 32 pixel right, left, and bottom border. This is undesirable because I would like the image for the cover block to occupy the full width of the page, matching the navigation block directly above it.  I've tried eliminating the border using CSS without success, and **that might be because I'm not properly referencing the specific element I want to change**.  For example, I tried without success:

```css
.wp-block-cover {
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

I've also tried using the Site Editor, but this theme does not have a border attribute for the cover block. I know the border is 32 pixels because I inspected the element and found the underlying code:

```css
element_style {
  border-right-color: var(--wp--preset--color--white);
  border-bottom-color: var(--wp--preset--color--white);
  border-left-color: var(--wp--preset--color--white);
  border-top-style: none;
  border-width: 0px 32px 32px;
}
```

I tried without success:

```css
.wp-block-cover {
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

as well as:

```css
.wp-block-cover_inner-container {
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: The border is not on `.wp-block-cover`, but the `.wp-block-group` element inside it. (And it is set via inline styling to begin with - so not sure if that actually comes from your theme, or was somehow added as "dynamic CSS" in the first place.)